# Laravel: passing a variable to multiple views

Tags: laravel

I would like to make the menu dinamically, so instead showing "FILMS OF THE MONTH" it shows "FILMS OF DECEMBER" (see the image); being December the current month that update itself each month

My problem is that the menu does not belongs to an specific route/controller, therefore I can not pass the variable like I do with other routes. Example:

```
    $month = Carbon::now()->format('F');
    return view('partials._nav')
            ->withMonth($month);
```

I could "solve" that problem passing the month to ALL controllers/routes, but I am repeating many times the same code.

**My questions are**

1- Is there any way in Laravel to pass a variable to a kind of rootstate (like in Angular) so, I keep the variable available in All routes of my application?

2- Is there any way that I could return a variable to more than one view? So I just pass the variable to all views possible like:

```
return view('films.all', 'films.show', 'films.index', 'actors.show', 'actors.index')
                ->withMonth($month);
```

Any idea would be appreciated

[image: The navigation is outside the scope of views]
**UPDATE**

[image: The menu is outside the views scope]

**Finally I have the solution:**

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $month = Carbon::now()->format('F');

        $view->withMonth($month);
    });
}
```

Comment: I know this is not your expected answer but.. https://www.sublimetext.com/ :)

Comment: @everytimeicob or He can buy PHPStorm Licence for versioning control, remote FTP, SFTP, Terminal access in development envrionment and a full development support (autocomplete etc....)

Comment: @Disfigure yes, I agree so MMB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AppServiceProvider`, you pass a variable through the layout that you extends.

Your code will be:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $var = 'value';

        $view->with('var', $var);
    });

    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $month = Carbon::now()->format('F');

        $view->withMonth($month);
    });
}
```

And you need to use the following class: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

Hope this works!

Comment: I used this solution , changing the line $var = 'value" with this -> "$var = Carbon::now()->format('F');" Since I want the value to be dynamic. I added use Carbon\Carbon at the top but the solution give me an error message: "FatalErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 26: Class 'App\Providers\View' not found"

Comment: It did not work. I get the error: Undefined variable: month (View: C:\Users\rra\Documents\Personal\Kino\resources\views\partials\_nav.blade.php). I think the problem is that I am trying to pass the variable $month into the layout, outside all the views. See the image, I updated the question

Comment: @RafaelMunoz I added the code, this will pas to all views in your view folder the variable. Now it will also pass to the views which extends the layout.

Comment: It finally worked, but I had to make some changes. See the update in the question

Comment: hi. How i can share a variable to a specified view like "admin.dashboard"?

Comment: @FarshidRezaei return view(‘admin.dashboard’, compact(‘varname’)); remind to not use the $ in the compact method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`share()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) method to share the data to multiple view. Place the following code in your `boot()` method of `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->share('key', 'value');
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: I try to understand what does it mean, but I have not clue how to use this in my solution. What is key?, what is value? I need to pass a variable $month that dynamically changes each month (january, february..) into all views.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Laravel Session.
You can save variable value in session and get it anywhere.

```
 //To Save value in Session
   $month = 'January';
   Session::put('currentMonth', $month);

 //To Get value from Session
   if((Session::has('currentMonth'))) {
       $month_var = Session::get('currentMonth');
    }
```